# removing users via powershell with multiple domains

Tags: powershell, windows-domain, acl

I have been trying to clean the permissions on a NAS via powershell for some time but I have hit an annoying problem.

presently I use

```
  foreach ($entry in $entries) {
        $acl = (Get-Item $QueryPath).GetAccessControl('Access')
        foreach($acc in $acl.access )
            {
            $val = $acc.IdentityReference.Value
            Write-Host "$val"
            if($val -match $entry)
            {  
                Write-Host "  ==  Removing $val ==  " -ForegroundColor Yellow
                $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($val,"FullControl","Allow")
                $acl.RemoveAccessRule($acc)  
                $acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($acc) # might be redundant but just incase...       
            }
        }
        Set-Acl -Path $QueryPath -AclObject $acl
    }
```

where $entry is a list of users/groups wanting to be removed and $querypath is derived from Get-ChildItem.

there is an isolated cluster of usernames and/or groups I am unable to remove via this method and it has taken some time but I have found the pattern.  Legacy domain group/permissions.

domain1\user1 ... domain2\user2

When viewing the permissions from windows explorer both users are listed. But when executing the above the script notes that there are two entries but only returns domain2\user2 twice.

Likewise a test with **(Get-Acl -Path $PATH).Access** equally returns two identical entries. As such I am unable to remove all the entries.

Any advice how to return all the information

Comment: Can you add an example of users in `$entries` from both domains, then compare to `(get-item $QueryPath).GetAccessControl('Access').Access.IdentityReference.Value` on a problem file? You may get long SIDs for other domains in some cases, or just fail to match for another reason.